# Neither Magento Session and Registry wont retain data as expected

Tags: php, magento, session, registry

We have a Magneto store that setup in 2 web servers behind a load balancer, which will take care of the load and send customers to either server. 
I have a Magento module thats allows customers to upload files through the website, which then  get saved in to, `[web_server_ip]/media/[visitor_id]/file_name.ext`

Since there are 2 servers web_server_ip has to be consistent throughout a customer session when they upload files. Means all files from a customer need to be in same directory in the same server that they got connected at first, regardless of which server they'll be sent by the load balancer within a single session. To ensure that I have following function to get the a consistent Server IP for file uploads.

```
protected function getServerIp() {
if (Mage::registry("dlite_server")!=""){
    $serverip = Mage::registry("dlite_server");
}else{
      if (substr($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],0,strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'], '.'))=='10'){
        //Private IP to Public IP conversion    
           if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '10.999.99.999'){
                $serverip = '50.99.999.999';
            }else if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '10.888.888.888'){
                $serverip  =  '50.888.88.888';
            }else{
                $serverip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
            }
        }else{
            $serverip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        }
    }
    Mage::register("dlite_server", $serverip);

            //I have used customer session as below to hold the IP first
    //Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setDliteServerIp($serverip);
    return $serverip;
}
```

The issue I'm facing is, I tried to hold the IP throughout the customer session using Magento's `customer/session` which failed 20% of the time. And as you can see now I'm trying to use `Mage::registry` to hold the IP, that fails even more, like 30% of the time.

So I was wondering is there any thing that's consistent in Magento that I can use to serve my purpose?